Adobe Acrobat - open advanced search by default
The "improved" UI these days does not show the advanced search in the toolbar, you have to click on search, which shows the pop-up dialog, click on three dots and click again for advanced search to get the actually useful search open. I can't figure out how you could stick the advanced search window to the toolbar or acrobat window either, it floats on its own, taking space on-screen.
There's an undocumented shortcut, shift-ctrl-f that will bring it up. That's somewhat awkward combination to type, though, at least on my keyboard, and I can't see any option to remap the key (to CTRL-F!).
Is there some trick (registry key?) that'd make the advanced search come up by default? Or at least make it easier to access than that finger-twister combo?
Foxit suffers from the same "improved" UI, it used to be the default search but no more.
